# Extending spock specification gives error in code

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

Geb Groovy and spock gurus, could you please help me understand why the following code doesn't work for me ( the variable 'closr' gives a null value)

```
import geb.Browser
import spock.lang.Specification

class somclass extends Specification{
def clos = {
    go()

    }
def Browser driveit(Browser browser, Closure script) {
    script.setDelegate(browser)
    script()
    browser
    }
}

objnew = new somclass()
def closr =  objnew.clos
objnew.driveit(new Browser(),closr)
```

While

```
import geb.Browser

class somclass {
def clos = {
    go()

    }
def Browser driveit(Browser browser, Closure script) {
    script.setDelegate(browser)
    script()
    browser
    }
}

objnew = new somclass()
def closr =  objnew.clos
objnew.driveit(new Browser(),closr)
```

this one does work for me( variable 'closr' has the closure returned ).? The only difference in the second one was I removed extending spock specification

Comment: Do we have to guess the error you get with the first version?

Comment: I get null on closr in the first one. Editing the question.

Comment: Why are you extending specification then calling this as a normal script (and not using any of Spock)?

Comment: I am using spock in my code. So looking for a way to use the spock specification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with this code, but Spock can't be used in this way. Spock specifications have to be executed via JUnit, and they have to conform to certain rules (e.g. test methods have blocks like `setup:` or `expect:`).

Comment: Spock specifications have to be executed via JUnit? thats new info.

Comment: @QVSJ it's in the 3rd sentence of [the project page](https://code.google.com/p/spock/)

Comment: @tim_Yates It says spock uses the Junit runner and it is inspired from Junit. How ever, if you have to use spock you dont have to import any Junit libraries , and would work fine with an import of spock.lang.specification. Just to clarify, I am not looking for an update on how I can use spock. In my code, I need to use spock to write tests which means, I use Given: When: Then: blocks and hence I can't help but use spock specification and import statements.At the same time I am looking for a solution for the problem i posted( looking to use the code with Given: When: Then: blocks).Hope it helps

Comment: Imports and class path are two different things. You do need JUnit on the class path, as a facade for executing Spock. To trigger execution manually, you can use the `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` class. Still don't understand which problem you are trying to solve, and what the intention of your code is.